# Same code structure - different results when calling .to_sql()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-requests, cx-oracle, pandas-to-sql

### **Background**

I have 3 separate python scripts that share the same structure and effectively do the same thing - call a request to an API, retrieve XML data, convert XML to ElementTree object then to pandas DataFrame object then use .to_sql() to import that dataframe into an oracle database. This was successful for two out of three of the scripts I have written but the third is not writing to the DB, there are no errors returned, the table is created empty, the script hangs

**Code from successful files:**

```
oracle_db = sa.create_engine('oracle://sName:sName@123.456.78/testDB')
connection = oracle_db.connect()
df.to_sql('TABLE_NAME', connection, if_exists='append',index = False)
```

I would post the code for the unsuccessful file but it is quite literally the same besides the table and variable name.

### What I have Tried

I have tried to use cx_oracle's engine to drive the connection to the
   DB with no success:

```
   conn = cx_Oracle.connect("sName", "sName","123.456.789.1/Test", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I have verified the dataframe is valid.

I have verified the connection to the DB.

Comment: Did you check to see if any other code (perhaps the first two scripts?) has an open transaction on the table in question? That would explain the hang quite nicely!

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga  No dice, I moved a 'connection.close()' to the front of the script to grab any open connections and while it doesn't throw an error the data is still not being written to the DB.

Comment: Check to see if there are any locks blocking the insert by looking at the ``dba_locks`` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - there was a column that was strictly integers so I had to specify the data type in the to.sql() call.